# Python strings: variables with LaTex-style formatting

Tags: python, string, format, latex

I am plotting a derivative, and using `legend`, I call it "dy/dx", but it is formatted thusly:

```
plt.legend(lineObjects, ("y", r"$\frac{dy}{dx}$"))
```

If it is the 2nd, or 3rd, or nth derivative, then I want it to display as: d^ny/dx^n.

So I tried the following:

```
  plt.legend(lineObjects, ("y",r"$\frac{d^{}y}{dx^{}}$".format(args.num,args.num)))
```

where `args.num` is the order of the derivative.

Didn't work.

I get an error:

```
plt.legend(lineObjects, ("y",r"$\frac{d^{}y}{dx^{}}$".format(args.num,args.num)))
KeyError: 'd^{}y'
```

Any ideas how I can print a LaTex-style formatted fraction with a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use `{` in a format string, you need to double it:

```
'This is {{}} a pair of curly braces in {}'.format('a string')
```

In other words, you want:

```
plt.legend(lineObjects, ("y",r"$\frac{{d^{}y}}{{dx^{}}}$".format(args.num,args.num)))
```

Alternatively, you can always fall back on the older %-style formatting:

```
plt.legend(lineObjects, ("y",r"$\frac{d^%sy}{dx^%s}$"%(args.num,args.num)))
```